# Samsung home page widget

Tags: bug, android-app

My home page stack exchange widget will often recommend a trending question from one of my communities, but when I select it, the app opens at the last question I viewed in-app. When I navigate back to the home screen and select the same trending question again from the widget it leads me to the correct page.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G920V

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G920VVRU4CPF4)

Comment: Screenshots please :)